# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: LEFT near line 1, column 24

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, sql-server-2012

I am trying to query data from database,but I wanna to remove the last three chars of specific column. The SQL is effective in SQL SERVER but when I put it into hibernate's syntax, eclipse showed as the title, the SQL context as follows:

```
String sql = "select distinct d.code,LEFT(d.VILLAGE, (LEN(d.VILLAGE)-3)) as village_name from DistrictInfo d where d.county=:region and d.town=:town and LEN(d.VILLAGE) !=0";
Query q = session.createQuery(sql);
q.setString("region", region);
q.setString("town", town)
```

The Specific exception as follows :

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: LEFT near line 1, column 24 [select distinct d.code,LEFT(d.VILLAGE, (LEN(d.VILLAGE)-3)) as village_name from org.nergis.orm.model.DistrictInfo d where d.county=:region and d.town=:town and LEN(d.VILLAGE) !=0]
```

Does the `LEFT()` cause the exception? How can I make it right?

Comment: I solved the exception by using Hibernate createSQLQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hibernate createSQLQuery for this .

Comment: Thank you, I have solved the exception as you tell me.